# Java command with flags runs in bash but not zsh

Tags: java, bash, proxy, zsh

I'm running into an issue where I'm able to run java with proxy settings in `bash` but not in zsh.

In order to run the jar, I'm first setting my proxy settings with an env variable:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=my.proxy.org -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -DsocksProxyHost=my.proxy.org -DsocksProxyPort=80"
```

Then I run the jar with the following

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar path/to/file.jar
```

It runs successfully in `bash`, but when running through `zsh`, it isn't able to recognize the proxy settings and it fails when trying to establish a network connection.

Anyone know how I can resolve this to be able to use `zsh`?

Comment: Is JAVA_OPTS defined in .zshrc, or do you have them defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zsh does word splitting differently from bash. I think you need to be explicit that you want to split it. Consider this, which acts like a bash quoted variable

```
$ export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=my.proxy.org -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -DsocksProxyHost=my.proxy.org -DsocksProxyPort=80"
$ printf ">%s<\n" $JAVA_OPTS
>-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=my.proxy.org -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -DsocksProxyHost=my.proxy.org -DsocksProxyPort=80<
```

versus this

```
$ printf ">%s<\n" ${=JAVA_OPTS}
>-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.org<
>-Dhttp.proxyPort=80<
>-Dhttps.proxyHost=my.proxy.org<
>-Dhttps.proxyPort=80<
>-DsocksProxyHost=my.proxy.org<
>-DsocksProxyPort=80<
```

See: `man zshexpn`

Comment: `java ${=JAVA_OPTS} -Xms4g -Xmx8g -jar out/fhir/guide/org.hl7.fhir.igpublisher.jar -ig out/fhir/guide/ig.json` works. Closing as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should be using an array, especially if you aren't actually relying on the variable being in the environment.

```
java_opts=(
 -Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.org
 -Dhttp.proxyPort=80
 -Dhttps.proxyHost=my.proxy.org
 -Dhttps.proxyPort=80
 -DsocksProxyHost=my.proxy.org
 -DsocksProxyPort=80
)

java "${java_opts[@]}" -jar path/to/file.jar
```